# Using select to find data in string with special characters

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to filter out records where one specific field has special characters with words in them.

For example:

```
-[ RECORD 1 ]--------------+------------------------------ 
id                         | 3151 
description                | Manual add from SCCM 
mac_address                | d4258be8d064 
status                     | Unknown 
mac_vendor                 | Intel Corporate 
added_by                   | Policy Manager 
added_at                   | 2019-02-19 14:29:21.802413+00 
updated_at                 | 2022-10-19 10:57:15.960282+00
attributes                 | {"Our Device": "true"}
extras                     |  
org_id                     | 1 
permit_id                  | 1
agentless_managed_endpoint | 0
```

I tried

```
select * 
from tips_endpoints 
where description = 'Manual add from SCCM' 
AND attributes = '{"Our Device": "true"}';
```

but it fails.

I need to be able to find records where attributes has value = {"Our Device": "true"}

Comment: What is the data type for `attributes`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select * 
from tips_endpoints 
where description = 'Manual add from SCCM' 
  AND attributes Like '%{"Our Device": "true"}%';
```

**UPD, for Postgres:**

```
select * 
from tips_endpoints 
where description = 'Manual add from SCCM' 
  AND attributes::text Like '%{"Our Device": "true"}%';
```

Comment: tipsdb=> select * from tips_endpoints where description = 'Manual add from SCCM' AND attributes Like '%{"Our Device": "true"}%';
ERROR:  operator does not exist: jsonb ~~ unknown
LINE 1: ...scription = 'Manual add from SCCM' AND attributes Like '%{"O...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: Ah, postgre.. Try something like this: 
select * from tips_endpoints where description = 'Manual add from SCCM' AND attributes::text Like '%{"Our Device": "true"}%';

Comment: You can say thank you by vote this comment up=)
Thank you

Comment: Done, hope I did it right.

Comment: @Rohit: using a JSON operator is the better approach here. Using LIKE is an ugly hack

Answer (score 1):

As the column is a `jsonb` column, a better approach would be to use one of the [JSON functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html)

```
and attributes ->> 'Our Device' = 'true'
```

or

```
and attributes @> {"Our Device": "true"}
```

Both expressions can be indexed if necessary.